# Replace textarea linebreaks in php

Tags: php, textarea, preg-replace

I am trying to change the output from $foo, replace linebreaks with ";". Here is an explanation and my preg match, however it does not work. The output is the same

```
<?php
/* $foo
1554
6554
5543
*/

preg_replace('/^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', ';', $foo);

# What I want: $foo = '1554;6554;5543'

?>
```

Does anyone know a preg replace I can use or any other method for doing this? These numbers are in a textarea, one number at each line.

Comment: str_replace("\n",";",$foo);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `preg_replace` for that. Try `str_replace`:

```
$foo = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n"), ';', $foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put anchor in your regex:

```
preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/m', ';', $foo);
```

Comment: Isn't the `m` modifier useless here ?